# Dynamically injecting multiple services into a directive in Angular 1.2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

Currently I am injecting a service into a directive like this

on my directive

```
<div myDirective myservice="service1"></div>
```

inside my directive link function js if I have something defined in my service I inject it like this

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs, c) {  

        if(attrs.validations){


            var myService = elm.injector().get(attrs.validations);
        }
```

Then I'm using this service when the something changes on my directive (its a select box) like this

```
elm.on("change",function(){  
    myService.myServiceFunction(myParams) 
  });
```

This all works fine. What I can't seem to get working is how inject multiple services eg

```
<div myDirective myservice="service1,service2"></div>.`
```

I have tried loading the services into array and injecting that way but I always get a not a function error when I try to call them.

I am using the injection method because the directive is part of a cms and the end user will define what appears in myservice. I don't know what will be in myservice. It could be 3 services there might be none.

I would really appreciate any guidance on this

Update

so I have set up a loop like this

```
 for(i =0; i < services.length; i++){

           $injector.get(services[i])


        }
```

Hower if I try and call these services i get a Uncaught ReferenceError telling me they are not defined?

Comment: elm.injector() is a hack. Use $injector. For `service1,service2` string split it into the array and call $injector.get for each element. Do you have problems with this approach?

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect where I am with it. Could you possibly give me a pointer?

Comment: It is not possible to figure out what's the problem. If you have error message, please, always post it *entirely*.